# ASP Server.Execute - Executed Page is not accessing variables from the former/first page

Tags: asp-classic

I already know that Server.Execute(..) does not accept query strings. The MSDN website says that all variables from the former website are avaible to the executed page. However it does not work for me at all. Any idea why?

Simple example that should work but it does not:

```
<%
    Dim strVar
    strVar = "This Text"
    Server.Execute("page2.asp")
%>
Page2.asp
<%
    Response.Write( strVar )
%>
```

any idea why this does not work?

ps. I´m not using "< !--include .. -->" because I have conditional outputs.

Comment: possible duplicate of [ASP 3.0 - Server.Execute Problems: Suffering from "ASP Amnesia" (Text Revised)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4997783/asp-3-0-server-execute-problems-suffering-from-asp-amnesia-text-revised)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using Server.Execute, variables from page 1 are not available on page 2, so by design your example should not work.

Here's a snippet from the [MSDN page for Server.Execute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525849(v=vs.90).aspx) that explains what is available from page 1 on page 2.

> The following collections and properties are available to the executed
>   ASP page:
>
> - Application variables, even if they are set in the calling page.
> - Session properties, even if they are set in the calling page.
> - Server    variables and properties, even if they are set in the calling page.
> - Request collections and properties, even if they are set in the    calling page. This includes Form and QueryString data passed to the calling page.
> - Response collections and properties. The executed .asp    file may modify HTTP headers. However, as with any .asp file, if the  executed .asp file attempts to modify HTTP headers after it sends a response to the client, it generates an error.

Comment: "Application variables.." I thought that would meant that the variable declared in the calling page would be avaible to the executed ASP page. Isn´t?

Comment: @Art Application variables are different from the variables you declare in your page. Application variables are like global variables available to all pages and accessible via an Application object like `Application("myVar")`. See [here](http://www.w3schools.com/asp/asp_applications.asp) for more.

Comment: Thanks Keith. I have just seen it now. For now I have only few parameters to send so I ended up using SESSION variables. I wonder what could be done in case of large query strings or parameters.

Comment: @Art According to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21076205/65775) you can pass values via the query string.